# How to avoid shrinking list when an element is removed in C#?

Tags: list, unity-game-engine

So I have a list in my Unity project, and when I remove one element from that list during play mode, for example from the first slot, the list is shrinking. I want to make that list to stay the same size as before, but I don't know how. Is there a way to for example, replace the removed object with a null object?

Also, here's that part of the code I'm talking about now:

```
public class Inventory : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<GameObject> items;

    public GameObject selectedGameObject;

    public int SelectedItem = 0;
    public int maxSlots;
    public int maxStack;

    public ItemSlot[] itemSlot;

    public void AddItem(string itemName, int quantity, Sprite itemSprite, string ItemDesc, GameObject itemObj)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < itemSlot.Length; i++)
        {
            if (itemSlot[i].IsFull == false)
            {
                itemSlot[i].AddItem(itemName, quantity, itemSprite, ItemDesc);
                items.Add(itemObj);
                selectedGameObject = itemObj;
                UpdateSelectedItem();
                return;
            }
        }

        SelectedItem = items.IndexOf(itemObj.gameObject);
    }
    
    public void RemoveItem(GameObject itemObj)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < itemSlot.Length; i++)
        {
            itemSlot[i].RemoveObj();
            items.Remove(itemObj);
        }
    }
}
```

I want to make a system that will allow me to remove object from a list without shrinking it whenever I call the RemoveItem().

The list of the objects is shrinking whenever I try to remove one element from there. I want that list to stay the same size, so even if the object gets removed the list size stays the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the index of the object you want to remove from the list and set it to `null`.

```cs
int index = items.IndexOf(itemObj);
if (index != -1) {
    items[index] = null;
}
```

Therefore, the modified `RemoveItem()` method would be:

```cs
public void RemoveItem(GameObject itemObj)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < itemSlot.Length; i++)
    {
        itemSlot[i].RemoveObj();
    }

    int index = items.IndexOf(itemObj);
    if (index != -1) {
        items[index] = null;
    }
}
```

In the above method, I moved the code that removes an object from the list outside the `for` loop, because it doesn't make sense to keep removing the same item multiple times from the list, which just adds load to the execution.